# Animate TranslateTransform.Y to a control's height (purpose is to slide element off sight)

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend, vsm

Given: Control (x:Name="border1") with a `VisualStateManager`. Control's `RenderTransform` is set to a `TransformGroup` that contains a `TranslateTransform`.

In `VisualState` "NotShown", `TranslateTransform`s `Y` property should be animated to a `Value` that is (at least) the height of the control being translated (effectively rendering it invisible - `ClipToBounds` set true).

This is the code Blend generates:

```
<VisualState x:Name="NotShown">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="border1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=border1}"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

EDIT (2): `{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=border1}`does not work at all. When run from VS instead of Blend, there is a hint:

> Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for
>   target element. BindingExpression:Path=ActualHeight; DataItem=null;
>   target element is 'EasingDoubleKeyFrame' (HashCode=57957548); target
>   property is 'Value' (type 'Double')

How do I properly set things up for the purpose of this animation?

Comment: Changed the part with speculation about what might go wrong... including VS output that I was not aware of before.

Comment: Update: Made EasingDoubleKeyFrame a Resource of border1. Now at least binding works. More to come...

Comment: ... and works as intended.
May I blame Blend for generating that code?

Comment: Not working well though... and Blend crashes when switching between states. :-/ Any comments on the hole topic?

Answer (score 0):

1. You are in the ControlTemplate, so you have to use `TemplateBinding` instead of `Binding`.
2. `Binding`/`TemplateBinding` only "works" on `FrameworkElement` (`EasingDoubleKeyFrame` is a `DependencyObject`, not a `FrameworkElement`). So you have to do your animation in code-behind.